# Remove r-th powers

Tags: code-golf

Given two numbers r and n on separate lines, write a program to print n natural numbers starting from 1 onwards, excluding the r-th powers. For example,

If `r=2` and `n=10`, the results would be `2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,13`

4 and 9 were excluded because 4 is `2^2` and 9 is `3^2`

```
Sample Input
2
10
Sample Output
2 3 5 6 7 8 10 11 12 13

Sample Input
3
30
Sample Output
2 3 4 5 6 7 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 28 29 30 31 32 33
```

1. `1 < r < 10`
2. `0 < n < 1,000,000`

> Since nobody came up with this, here's
>   a hint to reduce your solution sizes:
>
> The `i`th term of the output is given by
>   `floor(i+pow(i+pow(i,1/r), 1/r))`.

Comment: Is one number per line an acceptable output format?

Comment: Just printing numbers 2 to 1,000,000 with ruby/python take around 26 seconds on my dual core machine, I think your upper limit is too high, IMHO

Comment: @s-mark What if you print the output to the file? You can assume printing to files for large outputs.

Comment: @peter-taylor Yes.

Comment: @fR0DDY, Oh, ok if that is acceptable. I thought I have to output to console.

Comment: Printing a million numbers in Golfscript using `1000000,{p}/` (which should be efficient - I can't see why that wouldn't be linear time) takes 55 seconds on my 2.5GHz machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Golfscript, 18 characters

```
~.3*,.{3$?}%-@;<n*
```

Basically a direct port of my [Ruby solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2529/remove-r-th-powers/2536#2536). Also probably not completely golfed yet, I'll take a look at it later today again.

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, 56 characters

```
r,n=$<.map &:to_i;puts ([*l=1..2*n]-l.map{|i|i**r})[0,n]
```

Pretty straightforward (and similar to [Lars' solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2529/remove-r-th-powers/2535#2535)). Takes about 5 seconds to complete for `r = 2, n = 1000000` and 8 seconds for `r = 10, n = 1000000` here.

Comment: Nice improvement! Just had another of those "duh!" moments.

Answer (score 2):

#### Golfscript (<strike>18</strike> 17 chars)

```
~.3*,@{?}+1$%-<n*
```

This turns out to be similar to Ventero's solution, but slightly shorter (at time of writing!)

For a more efficient solution, 26 chars gives

```
~2.@{.2$4$?={)\)\}*.p)}*];
```

which uses the obvious algorithm:

```
int k = 2, x = 2;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (pow(k,r) == x) {k++; x++;}
    println(x++);
}
```

Comment: @S.Mark, I see what the problem is. Hopefully fixed, if not I'll have a look when I have access to the interpreter.

Comment: Seems to work now. You can save 2 characters by joining with `n` instead of `' '`  (see fR0DDY's comment on the question).

Comment: @Ventero, why do you think I asked that? By I think there might be potential for saving a couple more by rewriting with a loop using `p`.

Comment: Woops, didn't realize that you were the one who asked :)

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2, <strike>84</strike> <strike>83</strike>  80 chars

```
r,n=input()
r+=.0
i=c=1
while c<=n:
    p=i**(1/r)
    if p!=int(p):print i;c+=1
    i+=1
```

Runs in about 3 seconds for r=2, n=1000000

Answer (score 2):

**Python 68 Chars**

```
r=input();i=0;exec'i+=1;print int(i+(i+i**(1./r))**(1./r));'*input()
```

Answer (score 1):

### Windows PowerShell, 88

```
for($x,$r,[int]$n=,1+@($input);$n--){if((1..$n|%{[Math]::Pow($_,$r)})-eq$x){$x++}($x++)}
```

Fairly straightforward, but probably way too long.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby (<del>79</del> 77 chars)

```
n,r=$<.map &:to_i
a=(0..n*2).map{|x|[x,x**r]}.transpose
p (a[0]-a[1])[0,n]*?,
```

Yes, this does a lot of wasted effort, but it completes in about 8 secs
for n=1E6,r=10 on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 32

```
(4 :'y{.I.(~:<.)x%:i.1001000')/,
```

This assumes the input has the shape `2 1`, i.e., a vertical list of two rows with one atom per row, e.g.,

```
 2
10
```

This solution is instantaneous for r = 9, n = 999999, which (unless I've misread the question) are the upper bounds for the input parameters.

Answer (score 1):

### [Qwerty RPN](http://www.shinkirou.org/projects/qwerty-rpn) (52)

```
@=r@=n>L$i)=i$i 1$r/^:\=<S$n(=n$i#32.>S 0$n=<B 1<L>B
```

Ungolfed

```
@ =r  ; input number r
@ =n  ; input number n, counter variable

0 =i  ; the next number to be printed (pre-assigning variable is optional)
>loop ; label loop
  $i ) =i ; pre-increase i

  $i 1 $r / ^ : \ = <skipped ; skip printing and increasing counter n if i^(1 / r) == round(i^(1 / r))
    $n ( =n ; decrease n
    $i #    ; print number i
    32 .    ; print space
  >skipped

  0 $n = <break ; if n == 0: break loop
  1 ; TRUE
<loop  ; go back to beginning of loop
>break ; this is where the loop ends
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript, <s>118</s> 111 bytes

```
function d(r,n){for(var a=[],i=m=0,p=1;i<n;p++,m=Math.pow(p,1/r))if((m|0)!=m){a.push(p);i++}return a.join(" ")}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl - 51

```
map{print$_.$/if($_**(1/$ARGV[0])!~/^\d+$/)}1..pop;
```

Not quite up to spec, as it takes ~12/13s for r=10/n=1000000, and takes r/n as command line args instead of on separate lines -- but other than that it works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
+¹$r'¹Ėe:I≠
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%2B%C2%B9%24r%27%C2%B9%C4%96e%3AI%E2%89%A0&inputs=2%0A12&header=&footer=)

```
+¹$r        # Input range
'¹Ėe         # r-th root of each item in range
:I≠           # Filter roots with no fractional part
```

Comment: [9](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%9E'%E2%81%B0%C4%96e1%25%3B%E1%BA%8E&inputs=10%0A2&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

**C++, <del>97</del> <del>95</del> 90**

```
int main(){int r,s,n,m=0;cin>>r;cin>>n;s=r;while(m++!=n)r!=m?cout<<m<<' ',r*=r<m?s:1:++n;}
```

**(eventually +20)**

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Are you sure this is solving the correct problem? I don't see any raising numbers to powers.

Comment: It solves the wrong problem, indeed. Also it's missing a few namespace declarations somewhere and an `#include` to even compile. And my compiler tells me that `main()` as default-int isn't valid in C++.

Comment: sorry about that guys, thanks for support. glad your concerns joey, but my project file adds them by default. eventualy i can add using declaration.

Answer (score 0):

**Scala 172**

```
def p(r:Int,n:Int)={def f(n:Int):Stream[Int]=n#::f(n+1);lazy val i=f(0);lazy val o=i.filter(a => math.pow(a,1.0/r)!=math.pow(a,1.0/r).toInt);print(o.take(n).mkString(","))}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 60 bytes

```python
r,n=input();i=0
while n:
 i+=1
 if i**r**-1%1:
	print i;n-=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcTBCoAgDADQc37FLkEtBZe3ZJ9TOIglYkRfv3qHV99eLl3NmlcWrXef5iwc3VPk3EE3B7Iw/R8giA0x0EibG2oT7SBZA5NZ8il@)